# Appended html file which contain directive does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using the directive to call an external file and append it to html body.

In index.html

```
<li popup-url="template2.html" center-nav-popup></li>
```

In navpopup.js

```
angular.module('navPopup', [])
.directive('navPopup', [$document, $compile, $http, function($document, $compile, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                $document.on('click', function(event) if (element[0].contain(target.event)) {
                    handler();
                });

                function handler() {
                    $http.get(attr.popupUrl).then(function(response) { // retrieve the external html file
                        var $raw_html = response.data;
                        var template = angular.element($raw_html);
                        var $popup = $compile(template)(scope);
                        $document.find('body').append($popup);
                    });
                }
            }
        }]);
```

In popup.tpl.html template file, it contain the same directive again, just the file url is different. However, the directive doesn't work.

popup.tpl.html

```
<table id="single_dropdown">
  <tr><td> Item 1</td></tr>
  <tr popup-url="template3.html"center-nav-popup><td>Item 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td> Item 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td> Item 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/1gagvfj3/

```
angular.module('navPopup', [])
    .directive('navPopup', ['$document', '$compile', '$http', function ($document, $compile, $http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            // instead of binding to document click 
            //and validating it is current element, 
            //simply bind the event to the element
            element.on('click', function (event) {                                
                handler();                                
            });

            function handler() {

               $http.get(attr.popupUrl).then(function(response) {
                    // retrieve the external html file
                    var $raw_html = response.data;
                    var template = angular.element($raw_html);
                    $compile(template)(scope, function(ele) {
                        $document.find('body').append(ele);
                    }); 
                });
            }
        }
    }
    }]);
```

To work with templateCache, there are two ways.
1. define the Script tag with the type as "text/ng-template"

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
        <table id="single_dropdown">
        </table>
</script>
```

here id is similar to file name, so we can use the id in the nginclude.

2. Another ways is fetch the html from the server and put the content in the template cache as like below. Here check whether the template is available in the cache, if not fetch it from the server and put the retrieved response to the template cache and further onwards, the file content is used from the cache instead of retrieving from the server.

   ```
   link: function (scope, element, attr) {

           // instead of binding to document click and validating it is current element, simplt bind the event to the element
           element.on('click', function (event) {                                
               handler();                                
           });

           var appendPopUP = function(template) {
                $compile(template)(scope, function(ele) {
                   $document.find('body').append(ele);
               });  
           };

           function handler() {

               var $raw_html = $templateCache.get(attr.popupUrl);                
               if ($raw_html) {
                   appendPopUP(angular.element($raw_html));
               } else {
                   $http.get(attr.popupUrl)
                       .then(function(response) {
                    var $raw_html = response.data;
                    $templateCache.put(attr.popupUrl, $raw_html);
                    appendPopUP(angular.element($raw_html));
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Nice answer. But how can I get your solution to work with Angular templatecache?

Comment: Edited the content to use the template cache. updated fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/1gagvfj3/1/